# Publish something else than a jar with gradle to Nexus

Tags: gradle, ant, nexus, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm trying to use Gradle in combination with Ant to build our OpenEdge projects. OpenEdge is a 4GL language from some centuries ago. ;-)

Anyway, I've managed downloading some jar dependencies, but now I'm stuck in how to publish a PL file (Progress Library) to a Nexus repository. The thing is that like Maven, Gradle also seems to be made for Java projects.

This is my script (I also have a settings.gradle file with rootProject.name = 'stomp'):

```
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group 'be.mips'
version = '1.4.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  /*
  Gradle uses the same logic as Maven to identify the location of your local
  Maven cache. If a local repository location is defined in a settings.xml,
  this location will be used. The settings.xml in USER_HOME/.m2 takes precedence
  over the settings.xml in M2_HOME/conf. If no settings.xml is available, Gradle
  uses the default location USER_HOME/.m2/repository.
  */
  mavenLocal()
  maven {
    credentials {
      username '****'
      password '****'
    }
    url "http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/content/repositories/MadeApplReleases/"
    url "http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/content/repositories/MadeApplSnapshots/"
  }
  mavenCentral()
}

def stompProgressLibraryFile = file('dist/lib/STOMP.PL')

artifacts {
  archives stompProgressLibraryFile
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
      artifact stompProgressLibraryFile
    }
  }

  repositories {
    maven {
      // default credentials for a nexus repository manager
      credentials {
        username '****'
        password '****'
      }
      // url to the releases maven repository
      url "http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots"
    }
  }
}

configurations {
  antconf
}

dependencies {
  antconf 'be.mips:mips-progress-ant-tasks:1.5.8-SNAPSHOT',
  'be.mips:mips-pct:1.0-SNAPSHOT',
  'ant-contrib:ant-contrib:1.0b3'
}

/* Loads the jars */
ClassLoader antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
configurations.antconf.each {
  File f -> antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL())
}

/* Extend clean task */
clean.doFirst {
  delete '_ant_rcode', 'src', 'dist'
  println 'deleted directories'
}

/* Create dist/lib directory as prolib does not create directory automatically */
task init(dependsOn: clean) {
  doLast{
    project.file('dist/lib').mkdirs()
    println 'created dist/lib'
  }
}

ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

Running gradle publish gives me next output:

> C:\Workspace\git-repositories\OpenEdge\stomp.git>gradle
>   -DDLC=C:\OpenEdge\116\DLC publish :generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :processResources UP-TO-DATE :classes UP-TO-DATE :jar UP-TO-DATE
>   :publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository Could not find metadata
>   be.mips:stomp:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in remote
>   (http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots) Upload
>   http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots/be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.pom
>   Could not transfer artifact be.mips:stomp:pom:1.4.0-20161227.115652-1
>   from/to remote
>   (http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots): Could not
>   write to resource
>   'be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.pom'
>   Upload
>   http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots/be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.jar
>   Could not transfer artifact be.mips:stomp:jar:1.4.0-20161227.115652-1
>   from/to remote
>   (http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots): Could not
>   write to resource
>   'be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.jar'
>   Upload
>   http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots/be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.pl
>   Could not transfer artifact be.mips:stomp:pl:1.4.0-20161227.115652-1
>   from/to remote
>   (http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots): Could not
>   write to resource
>   'be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.pl'
>   :publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'.
>
>   > Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
>   >     Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact be.mips:stomp:pom:1.4.0-20161227.115652-1 from/to remote
>   >     (http://srv-ci-nexus:8082/nexus/repositories/snapshots): Could not
>   >     write to resource
>   >     'be/mips/stomp/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/stomp-1.4.0-20161227.115652-1.pom'
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.089 secs

The first thing I notice is having these java tasks that I do not need. :compileJava, :processResource, :classes, :jar ...

Basically I had a build.xml ant file doing everything I wanted. But the dependency management in ant is very poor. So I decided to use Gradle in combination with Ant. I want Gradle to do the dependency management for me. So far downloading dependencies seems to work fine (will have to try with a PL instead of a jar). But publishing something else than a jar, how do you do that?

Read a lot of the Gradle Online Documentation, but all the examples seem to be based on java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to compile java code, use [`base`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#sec:base_plugins) plugin instead of `java`. Also you should remove `from components.java`:

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifact stompProgressLibraryFile
    }
  }
}
```

Your next error *"Could not write to resource"* is most likely not a gradle problem, check write access to the repository. Before publishing to a remote repository, try to publish it in the local repository:

Apply plugin:

```
apply plugin: "maven"
```

Execute task `install`:

```
$ ./gradlew install
```

Comment: Thx! Already removed from components.java. Next I'll try the base plugin. Strange that such things are not all that well documented in the online Gradle User Guide...